# C: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, pthreads

I call the function `phtread_kill(gpsNavigationThread, 0)` and ge the following error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
"_phtread_kill", referenced from:
  _startgpswatchdog in ccXXNhjy.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I `#include <pthread.h>` so am not sure what the issue is.

I link as follows

```
gcc gps_nav.c dijk.c serial.c parser.c nav_corelogic.c -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -lm -lpthread -o logic
```

I also #include signal.h but am not sure if there is a library for linking with it.

Comment: are you compiling with specific -m flags? -m32 or -m64 ?

Comment: No. I use the statement above

Comment: What OS? I think people are assuming Linux, but modern Linux-based systems do not use underscore prefix for C symbol names. Perhaps you're mixing binary code intended for another OS?

Comment: @Helium3 sorry I had not seen it; and what about specifying one of -m32 or -m64, just to see if it is just a problem you are compiling in one way but the lib is available only as 32 or 64 bit... (afaik you cannot mix the thing in the same executable)

Comment: there's a typo!! (brain is able to autosort letters in wrong position in known words, so it can be missed, this is a proof of that!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's

```
pthread_kill(gpsNavigationThread, 0)
```

not:

```
phtread_kill(gpsNavigationThread, 0)
```

Comment: hehe. thanks for spotting this.

Comment: I did the same error with strcopy (it is strcpy)

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked with the pthreads library: -lpthread

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile with -lpthread ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-pthread` option, which should set the appropriate options for both compilation and linking.